# Access to private Bitbucket raw content with OAuth

Tags: oauth, bitbucket

With a private repo on github, I can generate a "personal access token" and

```
curl https://<oauth-secret>:x-oauth-basic@raw.githubusercontent.com/<me>/<repo>/master/<file>
```

and get the content of the file.  Is the same thing possible with bitbucket?

Answer (score 2):

Oh hey, it turns out you can just use http(s) authentication.

```
curl --user <username>:<password> https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>/raw/<file>
```

It's a bit of a bigger security hole having a username and password in a script than a token (for which you can restrict permissions), but it gets the job done in this case.

Answer (score 1):

According to [OAuth on Bitbucket Cloud](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html) you need to write `https://x-token-auth:{access_token}@bitbucket.org` so that you are using the token as password instead of username.

Answer (score 1):

Use [OAuth token](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html) and [Bitbucket api](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/src/%7Bnode%7D/%7Bpath%7D) with access_token param:

`https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/src/master/{file}?access_token={access_token}`

Comment: I'm trying this, however I'm presented with the following error: `{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Token is invalid or not supported for this endpoint."}}`